# live composer is not showing content in body

Tags: php, html, wordpress, customization

I am using theme Ds-orao of live composer but the problem is that whenever I used any automatically generated page of any other plugin like (memberpress, LearnDash, etc) some of the content goes up of the header or below the footer like: http://dev.lenguability.com/index.php/courses/lenguability-lecciones-gratuitas/

Please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

It can be the problem with css.Like when you add dynamic page using memberpress it adds more css that belongs to memberpress.
Try to check css in inspector if it is conflicting with any other css.

If not solve with this please let me know.